# TYPO3: Divider element is missing

Tags: element, typo3, divider

I have here a TYPO3 4.2.10 and I want do add a divider element (special element) in the content. But there is no divider element. Has anybody an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You might not have admin rights, or the user is not allowed to insert the page or content type "divider". Check the permissions at the user groups or users *Access Lists*.

For groups:

Module list > Page root > Backend usergroup
Edit the group you belong to.
Go to the tab *Access Lists* (check if necessary):

[image]

Scroll down and check if any options are explicitely denied:

[image]

Another way is to check the TSconfig for the user group, at the tab *Options*. The content element can also be disabled in the *Page TSconfig*, which can be found at the page settings, tab *Resources*. In both cases, check for this code:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems = div
```

and replace it by something suitable, e.g.:

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems >
```

[Source](http://www.mail-archive.com/typo3-german@lists.netfielders.de/msg06266.html)

Comment: User is admin. How can I find out if a user is not allowed to use the content type "divider"?

Comment: If you are admin, you have full rights, thus check ``UserTS`` and ``TSconfig``.

Comment: @pgampe: The `TSconfig` for my backend user is empty. Because I have admin rights there is no user group for me. There are some external ts-files included but up to now I didn't found the code mentioned by Mateng. The page where I want to use the divider element has an empty `TSconfig` field on the tab *Options* at the page settings. I also tried to use `TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems >` in the setup of the main template (pageid = 1) and the element is still not available. Currently, I'm using a HTML element with `<hr />`.

Comment: `TCEFORM.tt_content.CType.removeItems >` does not belong in the setup, you have to enter it to *Page TSconfig*, which can be found at the page settings, tab Resources. Also, I read that the divider element might have been disabled by default in TYPO3 4.2 (and enabled again in later versions). http://lists.typo3.org/pipermail/typo3-german/2008-October/051642.html

Comment: You might as well consider updating to 4.5, as 4.2 is not supported anymore.

Comment: Use the info module to check the actual `TSconfig` as it might be inherited by a page up in the rootline or by the default `TSconfig`.

Comment: Now I have a Typo 4.2.8 with the same effect. There is still no divider element available. I checked the info module and the value for CType removeItems does not exist. I put your posted code on the root page in the TSconfig field (tab Options). How can I enable the divider element for TYPO3 4.2? With your posted code?